using vtk visualized stereocalibration camera pose
stereocabration result:cameraMatrix1、cameraMatrix2、distCoeffs1、distCoeffs2、R1、R2、T1、T2
As follows:
distCoeffs1: !!opencv-matrix
rows: 1
cols: 5
dt: d
data: [ -2.8688541223223285e-02, 6.6253118209987050e-01, 0., 0.,
-7.0104939030577000e+00 ]
distCoeffs2: !!opencv-matrix
rows: 1
cols: 5
dt: d
data: [ -4.1635318320200697e-02, 2.1377494902796179e-01, 0., 0.,
3.4222979503325810e+00 ]
cameraMatrix1: !!opencv-matrix
rows: 3
cols: 3
dt: d
data: [ 6.3624454120522842e+03, 0., 1.3226910442379431e+03, 0.,
6.3599760904886944e+03, 9.8157165150913215e+02, 0., 0., 1. ]
cameraMatrix2: !!opencv-matrix
rows: 3
cols: 3
dt: d
data: [ 6.3935827973198029e+03, 0., 1.2867587476385670e+03, 0.,
6.3946057715948709e+03, 1.0416304396474293e+03, 0., 0., 1. ]
R1: !!opencv-matrix
rows: 3
cols: 3
dt: d
data: [ 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1. ]
R2: !!opencv-matrix
rows: 3
cols: 3
dt: d
data: [ 8.7596956658019609e-01, -3.1782892098268485e-03,
-4.8235590273469464e-01, -8.1664246812940926e-03,
9.9973725954203274e-01, -2.1417782128665196e-02,
4.8229724022974485e-01, 2.2700448477616427e-02,
8.7571345867565997e-01 ]
T1: !!opencv-matrix
rows: 3
cols: 1
dt: d
data: [ 0., 0., 0. ]
T2: !!opencv-matrix
rows: 3
cols: 1
dt: d
data: [ 2.3661722814185414e+03, 6.2769125562187838e+01,
6.6154694678412784e+02 ]
I want to use vtk to achieve something similar to matlab plotcamera,can anyone help me？
vtkSmartPointer<vtkCamera> CreateCamera(double focal_length, double principal_point[2]) {
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkCamera> camera = vtkSmartPointer<vtkCamera>::New();

    camera->SetViewAngle(2 * atan(principal_point[0] / focal_length));
    camera->SetPosition(principal_point[0], principal_point[1], focal_length);
    camera->SetFocalPoint(principal_point[0], principal_point[1], 0);

    return camera;
}

vtkSmartPointer<vtkCameraActor> CreateCameraActor(vtkSmartPointer<vtkCamera> camera, vtkSmartPointer<vtkMatrix4x4> rt) {
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkTransform> transform = vtkSmartPointer<vtkTransform>::New();
    transform->Identity();
    transform->SetMatrix(rt);
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkCameraActor> camera_actor = vtkSmartPointer<vtkCameraActor>::New();
    camera_actor->SetCamera(camera);
    camera_actor->SetUserTransform(transform);

    return camera_actor;
}
auto  matrixL = OpenCVRTtoVTKMatrix(R1, T1);
    auto  matrixR = OpenCVRTtoVTKMatrix(R2, T2);
    double focal_length1 = cameraMatrix1.at<double>(0,0);
    double focal_length2 = cameraMatrix2.at<double>(0, 0); 
    double principal_point1[2] = { cameraMatrix1.at<double>(0,2), cameraMatrix1.at<double>(1,2) }; 
    double principal_point2[2] = { cameraMatrix2.at<double>(0,2), cameraMatrix2.at<double>(1,2) }; 
                                                  
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkCamera> camera1 = CreateCamera(focal_length1, principal_point1);
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkCamera> camera2 = CreateCamera(focal_length2, principal_point2);

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkCameraActor> camera1_actor = CreateCameraActor(camera1, matrixL);
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkCameraActor> camera2_actor = CreateCameraActor(camera2, matrixR);
    vtkNew<vtkSphereSource> sphereSource;
    sphereSource->SetPhiResolution(31);
    sphereSource->SetThetaResolution(31);

    vtkNew<vtkPolyDataMapper> sphereMapper;
    sphereMapper->SetInputConnection(sphereSource->GetOutputPort());
    vtkNew<vtkActor> sphere;
    sphere->SetMapper(sphereMapper);
    vtkNew<vtkNamedColors> colors;
    vtkColor3d sphereColor = colors->GetColor3d("Banana");
    sphere->GetProperty()->SetDiffuseColor(sphereColor.GetData());
    sphere->GetProperty()->SetDiffuse(.7);
    sphere->GetProperty()->SetSpecular(.3);
    sphere->GetProperty()->SetSpecularPower(30.0);
    sphere->SetPosition(0, 0, 0);
    render_->AddActor(camera1_actor);
    render_->AddActor(camera2_actor);
    render_->AddActor(sphere);

